# How does the "spell combo" technique work?

Tags: warlock-master-arcane

Sometimes enemy great mages cast spells that trigger quite devastating "spell combo" effects having AoE impact. How this "spell combo" mechanic work and how to trigger it? Is there a list of spells that when cast one after another may lead into a combo? Or is it depending on unit that is targeted? What are the approximate chances of triggering spell combos?